# Docker client cannot connect to daemon version 1.9: connection reset by peer

Tags: docker, ubuntu-12.04

I installed the new version of Docker (1.9.0) on Ubuntu 12.04 yesterday. But when I run any docker command they always show the below logs, maybe the docker client cannot connect to docker daemon:

```
root@localhost:$docker ps
An error occurred trying to connect: Get `http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.21/containers/json: read unix /var/run/docker.sock: connection reset by peer`

root@localhost:$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.9.0
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   76d6bc9
 Built:        Tue Nov  3 17:40:31 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
An error occurred trying to connect: Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.21/version: read unix /var/run/docker.sock: connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Any chance you could upgrade Ubuntu? (as in https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15651#issuecomment-136491658)

Answer (score 4):

We had the same problem and this solved (on ubuntu trusty): https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17846#issuecomment-155233858

1. `sudo service docker stop`
2. `sudo rm /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db`
3. `sudo service docker start`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem,
With version 1.9, docker change the IP address of its network interface (`docker0` you can see it when type `ifconfig` on host machine) to `172.17.0.1` instead of `172.17.42.1` of previous version

Comment: how did you fix it?